# Evolutions not working in play framework functional tests

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a play application with evolution scripts. I just added 2.sql and now the functional tests all fail.

I'm simply running tests using

```
running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("default", ImmutableMap.of("MODE", "MYSQL")))), ()-> ...
```

However running the second evolution fails with " play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi - Duplicate column name".

I tried stepping through the evolution runner and in line play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsApi.scala:196 I can see the scripts contains the actual script from 2.sql, but script 1 in the list seems to be a generated create script which includes the column 2.sql is adding.

How do I get inMemoryDatabase to run the actual evolution scripts?

Can I have it only run the generated script and not 2.sql?